# Schema Structure for JOIN-like Operations in MongoDB with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a NodeJS application with MongoDB and I'm looking to replicate the behavior of a SQL INNER JOIN using Mongoose. I've attempted several tutorials and methods, but I'm not getting the desired outcome. I have the following schema setup:

```
const domainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  domain: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  portfolioId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Refers to an Object ID in the portfolioSchema
    required: true,
    ref: 'Portfolio'
  },
});

const portfolioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  portfolioName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  userIds: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Refers to an Object ID in the userSchema
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  emailAddress: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  // Other user fields...
});
```

I've structured my schemas with reference IDs, assuming that's how you set up relations in Mongoose. Given only the user's ID, my goal is to fetch all portfolios associated with that user and the domains within each portfolio. Is this schema structure appropriate for that purpose?

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on the specific MongoDB and NodeJS code to perform this operation. Thanks!

Comment: Does a `portfolio` belong to 1 user? Your naming of your key `userIds` suggests multiple users but I just want to make sure that `userIds` is referring to 1 single user id.

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose you can use [Model.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to execute a lookup from one collection to another. That is synonymous with a left join in SQL (but not quite). The `populate` method will replace all of your referenced `ObjectId` values in the document with their corresponding document from the other collection.

So in this example:

```js
const Domain = mongoose.model("Domain", domainSchema);
const Portfolio = mongoose.model("Portfolio", portfolioSchema);
const domains = await Domain.find().populate({path: 'portfolioId', model: Portfolio});
```

`const domains` would now hold all `Domain` documents with all of the `Portfolio` documents contained inside instead of just their ids.

The issue with `popluale` is that you can't filter the parent documents based on the child document. So you can't `populate` `Portfolio` into `Domain` and then get rid of the `Domain` results that don't have a `Portfolio` you want. You need to use [aggregate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for that.

However, you seem to be starting off with a `User._id` value which would mean you could easily query the `portfolios` collection but then you would have to do another database query to the `domains` collection to find the matching `portfolioId` from the previous results.

Based on your current Schema design my recommendation would be to perform an `aggregate` query on the `Domain` model.

Given a `User` document with the following `_id`:

```js
{ _id: ObjectId("650ecb80507561a33ce927a3"), emailAddress:"bob@gmail.com"}
```

The following query will return desired results:

```js
const documents = await Domain.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "portfolios",
      "localField": "portfolioId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "portfolioId"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "portfolioId.userIds",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "userIds"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "portfolioId.userIds": ObjectId("650ecb80507561a33ce927a3")
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pt3dNhaRkfD) for a working example.

**Edit**:

Alternatively, if you are able to remodel your schemas then you can add a `Domain` reference to your `Portfolio` schema and that would allow you to search the `portfolios` collection. Update your `portfolioSchema` like so:

```js
const portfolioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  portfolioName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  userIds: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Refers to an Object ID in the userSchema
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  domainId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Refers to an Object ID in the domainSchema
    required: true,
    ref: 'Domain'
  },
});
```

Now you can use [Model.populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) like this:

```js
const Domain = mongoose.model('Domain', domainSchema);
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Portfolio = mongoose.model('Portfolio', portfolioSchema); 
const portfolios = await Portfolio.find({
      userIds: ObjectId("650ecb80507561a33ce927a3")
   }).populate({
      path: 'userIds', 
      model: User
   }).populate({
      path: 'domainId', 
      model: Domain
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, it is the case that in the domainObject the portfolios are shown. Can it be the other way around? So that you first see the Portfolios and in them the Domains that are included in the portfolio?

Comment: @lumper007 yes that it possible. You would need to remodel your data such that you store a reference to the domain in each portfolio. That would allow you to search the portfolio and use the mongoose `Model.populate` method rather than doing `$lookup` twice. You can still use `aggregate` if you wish and if you intend to do document transformations then I would encourage `aggregate` but for simple queries `populate` is best. I will update the answer to give you an example.

Comment: Is it also possible without mentioning the domainId in the portfolio? The reason behind this is that a domain name should always be able to be in no more than one portfolio.

Comment: No that's not possible when using referenced documents. In order to populate the domain into a portfolio or do the lookup you need an id or some other identifier stored in the portfolio document. However, mongodb is flexible. You can just store the actual domain document in the portfolio document. This approch is known as [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). It would be `domainId: domainSchema` inside the `portfolioSchema`.

Comment: @lumper007 if you found the answer useful please consider [marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.).